# Select ISNULL is not returning replacement value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

`ContactPerson` type is nvarchar.

The issue is when `ContactPerson` is empty not returning `n/a`

**Query**

```
Select ISNULL(ContactPerson,'n/a') from [dbo].[Suppliers]
```

Comment: `NULL` is not the same as "empty". Is the value `null` or the empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty string (`''`) and not the same thing as a null value. `ISNULL()` returns the replacement value only for an actual null value.

You can use `NULLIF()` to evaluate an empty string into a null value:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(ContactPerson, ''), 'n/a') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) instead of ISNULL, with [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(ContactPerson,''),'n/a') 
FROM [dbo].[Suppliers]
```

You can find the difference of COALESCE and ISNULL f.e. [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull).